# TypeScript: Assert all optional properties of T as non-optional

Tags: typescript

Given the type `T`, I want create a type helper that will assert that optional properties are not optional.

---

e.g.

```
type Foo {
    foo?: string;
    bar: number | null;
}

type NoOptionals<T> = /* ??? */;

type FooNoOptionals = NoOptionals<Foo>;

// this will be equal to:
// type FooNoOptionals = { foo: string; bar: number | null };
```

Note that I don't want to remove `null`s if they are present, just optional properties ideally.

This is what I've tried:

```
type NoOptionals<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends undefined ? never : NonUndefined<T[P]>;
};

type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
type NonUndefined<T> = Diff<T, undefined>;
```

---

It sort of works. If you have a type like `{ foo: string | undefined }` then it will correctly convert it to `{ foo: string }`. However, if you have the type `{ foo?: string }`, then the resulting type is `{ foo: string | undefined }`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgMwQHgCoBooFUB8UC8UqUEAHsBAHYAmAztlAPxSUQBuEATlAFxEDcAKFCQoAOQD2lLDQgI4ramjyF4SNJgCus+YpxDh4aJIDyYYHCkBDADa1lBKAG9BUN1ADaABSgKoAawgQCQQiAF0+VG8wknIqOihtajkFCGomFnYuXnEpGWTdNLRo-UEAXwMRaAAxCQlHF3coBDrGPlpgTgUAcyEmgCMrTj5KTQBbfuyAHxZNGxs+936bKwALds6eqBmklMUhMsFBAHpjqFWJDm5L7OBVuHoqk7OmqEBeDcBxHcNRWolTc0slFs9EI-ws1jsyF+pVOLAkFgAxtA7lZgFAAAa-MGA4EeADkyzWeLC6N89AREk4nAgCOANhAGI6XUo3XRzyg-U0aMxdWxENo+JaEmJZN8lApVJpdIZ6KZWx2OlS1HRQA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
type NoOptionals<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: T[P];
};
```

With the minus before `?` you can remove the optionality.

Edit: yet implemented `Required<T>`

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5fc917be2e4dd64c8e9504d36615cd7fbfdd4cd3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1446

Comment: This solved my problem however I just found out about [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredt). Can you include this in your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The [implementation of `Required`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5fc917be2e4dd64c8e9504d36615cd7fbfdd4cd3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1448-L1450) is exactly the same as your answer.

Comment: @RicoKahler added :)